# Docker run/star/exec?

Tags: bash, docker

Hi i have build and install ziftrCoin wallet on a ubuntu image.

```
8084e9de3c23 ubuntu:latest "/bin/bash" 25 hours ago Up About a minute 0.0.0.0:10332->10332/tcp ziftrCoin
```

The problem is that ziftrcoind closing after i exit the container.
Try to run `docker exec -it ziftrCoin /root/64/./ziftrcoind` the program start but i get connected to the container. Same problem if i exit.

So how to update / edit the COMMAND when i start the container with `"ziftrCoin /root/64/./ziftrcoind"` and not `"/bin/bash"`?

---

UPDATE

IF i build it  run it i dont get it to stay open..

```
docker run -d ziftr
252554f38c2a41bdd29875bcb6ab7b6bbe98522e16828b1f8b06d8899bc5134c

docker run -it ziftr
ZiftrCOIN server starting

FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Krister Johansson <hello@nodejs.how>
WORKDIR /var/ziftrCoin
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget "https://d19y4lldx7po3t.cloudfront.net/assets/downloads/0.9.3/ziftrcoin-0.9.3-linux64.tar.gz"
RUN tar -xvzf ziftrcoin-0.9.3-linux64.tar.gz
RUN rm ziftrcoin-0.9.3-linux64.tar.gz

ADD ./src/ziftrcoin.conf /root/.ziftrcoin/ziftrcoin.conf

EXPOSE 10332 11332
CMD ["64/./ziftrcoind"]
```

Comment: The `-d` flag runs the container in daemon mode, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found!

I had deamon=1 in ziftrcoin.conf after removing it it workt!

Uploaded it to git.
https://github.com/nodejshow/docker-ziftrcoind

Answer (score 2):

For Docker, when the process with pid 1 (inside the container) quits, it will quit too (and kill all other processed that were running in that container). This is what happens to you as `/bin/bash` is the process with pid 1. What you need to do is set `ziftrcoind` process as **pid 1**.

You did not provide a `Dockerfile` or a `docker run` command but I assume you run something like `docker run ziftrcoin` (where ziftrcoin would be the name of the image you build) and you don't have a `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`.

The idea would be either to give docker a default command, using `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` or give it the command to run when issuing the `docker run`.

Let's see the how the `Dockerfile` would look like :

```
FROM Ubuntu
RUN # … Install ziftrcoind
CMD ["/root/64/./ziftrcoind"]
```

If you build this image, when running it, the default command would be `/root/64/./ziftrcoind` instead of `/bin/bash`. You could also do `docker run ziftrcoint /root/64/./ziftrcoind` to achieve the same *effect*.

As Kevan Ahlquist commented, if you want to run it in background, you can use the flag `-d` : `docker run -d ziftrcoin` (with or without the command, depending if you have the `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` or not).

Comment: I did use "docker run --name ziftrCoin -d -it -p 10332:10332 ubuntu /bin/bash" and then install ziftrCoin on it. So there wher no image file. But mabe it is better to do that?

Comment: yes you should either commit your container to a file (using docker commit) or using a Dockerfile to automate the creation ;-)

Comment: How to do the "pid 1"

Comment: The best way would be to do a Dockerfile (like above) with the command(s) you used to install ziftrcoind. Then ``docker build -t ziftrcoind .``. That way you have a image you can run as much as you want (and if you push it, wherever you want). To run it, you could do ``docker run -d --name myziftrcoind ziftrcoind`` and it would run (in background).

Comment: docker run -d ziftr
252554f38c2a41bdd29875bcb6ab7b6bbe98522e16828b1f8b06d8899bc5134c

i get that as an awnser, but when i do docker ps the docker image is not running..

Comment: why the hash ? (look at https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/). You can do a ``docker ps -a`` to see the "stopped" containers, and ``docker logs 252554f38c2`` to see the logs (and so be able to know what happened).

Comment: Well the hash is the response when i run the command run -d ziftr
I will look in the log

Comment: LOG
`ZiftrCOIN version v0.9.3.0-gd75ade3-beta (Sat, 28 Feb 2015 23:35:24 -0500)
Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
Default data directory /root/.ziftrcoin
Using data directory /root/.ziftrcoin
Using at most 125 connections (1048576 file descriptors available)
Using 4 threads for script verification
Using wallet wallet.dat`

No more :/